# Calculate the rolling time since an event for each record in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-columns

I am working on a query to calculate the time since the latest preventative maintenance (PM) for each piece of equipment on a rolling calendar. The goal is build a dataframe to analyze when a repair will take place.

Below is a table of the query results that I have with the added column "Time Since Last PM" which is the column that I want.

Call this Table 1:

```
EquipmentNumber |Year   |weeknumber |Current Week Repair|Time Since Last PM  
2069186         |2018   |10         |1                  |5  
2069186         |2018   |21         |1                  |1  
1626930         |2018   |09         |1                  |21  
1626930         |2019   |03         |1                  |15
```

The preventative maintenance data comes from a query/table that is set up like the following i.e. Table 2.

```
Equipment Number |Year  |WeekNumber  
2069186          |2018  |5  
2069186          |2018  |20  
1626930          |2017  |40  
1626930          |2018  |40
```

So I need to make sure that for my final query, Table 1, the “Time Since Last PM” for equipment 2069186 the first record is difference from week 5 2018 in Table 2 to week 10 2018. For the second record of equipment 2069186 the “Time Since Last PM” should be the difference between week 21 2018 in Table 1 and week 20 2018 in Table 2. For equipment 1626930 the first record should be the difference from week 9 2018 in Table 1 to week 40 2017 in Table 2. For equipment 1626930 the second record should be the difference from week 3 2019 in Table 1 to week 40 2018 in Table 2. Keep in mind that I want the difference between the current record in Table 1 and the latest PM prior to the year and week in Table 1.

The queries for Table 1 and Table 2 are very basic.

```
 SELECT   
 DISTINCT EquipmentNumber,
 Year, 
 weeknumber,
 [Current Week Repair]
 FROM TableA

 SELECT 
 EquipmentNumber,
 DatePart(Year, Created) as Year,
 DatePart(Week, Created) as WeekNumber
 FROM TableB
```

Any suggestions on the proper way to join the two tables and make the calculation? Or is there a way to utilize temp tables and variables that anyone can suggest? Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: SQL server version?

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t1.WeekNumber - ca.WeekNumber
FROM t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Year, WeekNumber
    FROM t2
    WHERE Equipment_Number = t1.Equipment_Number
    AND (
        (Year < t1.Year)
        OR
        (Year = t1.Year AND WeekNumber < t1.WeekNumber)
    )
    ORDER BY Year DESC, WeekNumber DESC
) AS ca
```

Calculating week number difference will be tricky and for that you'll need the number of weeks in the previous year.

Comment: That did the trick! Appreciate it. I had never heard of the "Apply" function in SQL Server before, but I will need to learn more about it for future projects.